# how can i integrate tfs database and sql server database to generate reports in tfs

Tags: sql-server, tfs

We are planning to store the automation test results in a database so that we have a historical record of the results. So I have designed a data base in the SSMS(SQL Server Management Studio). We now want to integrate this database with the TFS, so that every one in  the team has easy access to the results. Does any one have a solution to do it.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "integrate with TFS"

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [test tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Test/automated-tests/test-build) in your build definitions then the results will be automated stored in TFS. No need for custom database.

Comment: If you have a custom test framework you can add that data directly to tfs using the api as part of a build, or as part of a manual test run.